# Can't figure out how to make the relation between this 3 tables to make a Cascading LOV on Apex

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.
I have 3 views made from synonims from remote database:

1. Rank: RANK_ID, DESCRIPTION
2. Class: CLASS_ID, DESCRIPTION
3. Rank_Class: RANK_ID, CLASS_ID, RC_ID

I need to have 2 LOV.

1. LOV Rank -> shows all the Ranks
2. LOV Class -> shows only the Classes from that Rank

I don't know, using Cascade Lov on APEX, using the List of Values -> QUERY, how to achieve this.

Can anyone teach me *what query* should I make?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

*p1_item_1:*
**LOV Type:** SQL Query
**Query:**

```
select description, rank_id as return_value from table_a;
```

*p1_item_2:*
**LOV Type:** SQL Query
**Query:**

```
select x.rank_id, y.class_id from table_a x, table_b y
where y.class_id = x.class_id
and x.rank_id = :p1_item_1;
```

**cascading List of Values:** p1_item_1

I think it is basically something like this. However, is there a relation between your tables? I mean it's not a matter of cascading 2 items. if you can write a query by joining your tables and execute it with a bind variable and get the result you wished to see on your sql client, you can cascade your LOVs too.

Comment: Yes, table 3 as the relation between the other 2. I am still learning SQL too that is why I am a little lost on this.